# Variance Column in BI Publisher Report Pivot Table

Tags: obiee, bi-publisher

I have a data model using a private data source (not from a Subject Area), so I need to do this with a BI Publisher Report (not an Analysis).

In the data model I have a column called 'Financial Plan Type' that contains a few different values such as "Forecast", "Adjusted Budget", "Original Budget", etc.

I want to create a pivot table that pivots this column and then creates a variance column between "Adjusted Budget" and "Forecast" as example.  Obviously I have an 'Amount' field in the table too.

It doesn't seem that I can do this directly in the report as the formulas and flexibility seem to be limited for the Reports (although I'm not 100% sure of this as I am fairly new to OBIEE), but I was thinking that I could adjust the data model to union in a variance amount or do something else with the data model to make this work.  Does anyone have any ideas and/or best practices around doing this either in the data model or in the Report itself?

Answer (score 0):

This going to be abstract, but you can do this in BIP or Analysis, depends on what the data source looks like.

If you have are able to compute the variance as an extra element in the datasource (might need to model it), then BIP RTF template designer does support Pivot tables. You might still need to add some XDO code in the loops.

If you are inclined to OBIEE, you can create your OWN data source on OBIEE. You will have to use the [RPD data modeller](https://businessintelligenceblogs.wordpress.com/category/uncategorized/page/2/) if you are on OBIEE on premise, or write the [transactional SQL](https://blogs.perficient.com/2017/02/28/using-custom-sql-bip-to-extract-erp-cloud-data-from-otbi/) if you are OTBI on the cloud.

Either way, the trick is to have the variance already computed in the XML, so BIP/OBIEE can simply print it off.

Comment: thank you for the response. so, I am able to model a variance in the data source, but I'm not sure how to use xdo code? any good references for this?

Comment: Check if you can use the RTF template to create the pivot table. That will create the code for you in the template. That is the code I was talking about, which can be modified per your requirements.